# Gmail images are requested through Google's Image Proxy and not the IP of the user who opened the email

Tags: email, gmail, ip

I noticed that all requests to load images from my server in Gmail come through Google's Image Proxy service under IP 66.249.93.42

Is there any way to know what the source IP that initiated the request? My server performs some localization logic based on the originating country of the request -  and at the moment it appears that all Gmail users are 'physically' located in Mountain View, CA when they are obviously not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail will only serve images though Google's own proxy servers, according to the [official Gmail blog](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2013/12/images-now-showing.html). They also do this to prevent senders from getting the recipient's IP address.

> Gmail serves all images through Google’s image proxy servers and
>   transcodes them before delivery to protect you in the following ways:
>
> Senders can’t use image loading to get information like your IP
>   address or location.

However, in my experience, if the recipient is checking their emails inside Outlook or another mail client, the IP address is passed when requesting the image assets.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it makes sense from a security perspective.